# Filter option in form select in React js

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am new to reactJs. I am using react-bootstrap and am using `<Form.Control as = 'select'>` to show options from my database.

The code is here below:

```
<Form.Group controlID="Department">
    <Form.Label>
        Department
    </Form.Label>

    <Form.Control as = 'select'>
        {this.state.deps.map(dep =>
        <option key={dep.DepartmentID}>{dep.DepartmentName}</option>
        )}
    </Form.Control>

</Form.Group>
```

I was wondering can I add a filter option at the top where I can search for my elements in react-bootstrap. If so please help with examples

Answer (score 0):

1. I highly recommend using functional components with hooks
2. You can simply add a filter in your state and change your code to

```
{this.state.deps.filter(dep=>dep[value]===this.state.filter).map(dep =>
        <option key={dep.DepartmentID}>{dep.DepartmentName}</option>
        )}
```